# How to paginate search results in Django 1.7?

Tags: html, django, django-templates, django-views

The code I have is a pager that works for me very well, but now I would like to add the option to search but I do not know how to integrate it with my code, I appreciate all the help provided.

This is my url:

```
url(r'negocios/(?P<pagina>\d+)/$', NegociosView.as_view(),name='vista_negocios'),
```

This is my view:

```
class NegociosView(ListView):

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):


    pagina = kwargs['pagina']
    lista_negocios = Perfil.objects.all()
    paginator = Paginator(lista_negocios,2)
    try:
        page = int(pagina)
    except:
        page = 1
    try:
        nego = paginator.page(page)
    except(EmptyPage,InvalidPage):
        nego = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    ctx = {'negocios':nego}
    return render_to_response('home/negocios.html',ctx,context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

This is my template code:

[image]

This is the view from the browser:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if request.GET.get('search'):
    lista_negocios = Perfil.objects.filter(myfield=request.GET['search'])
else:
    lista_negocios = Perfil.objects.all()
```

Then in url, access as

```
full_url/?search=search_string
```

Comment: How can I modify the template?